# On what basis Avataras are classified as Rudra Avatar & Vishnu Avatar?

Tags: avatars, brahman

When àtmà is the one & indwelling in both Lord Shiva or Lord Vishnu and When same àtmà manifests or descents on the earth, then why some Avatars are called Shiva Avatars or some Vishnu? On what basis?

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54513/discussion-on-question-by-seeker-when-atma-is-the-one-indwelling-in-both-lord).